# How can I estimate theta for the inverse hyperbolic sine transformation?

Tags: r, data-transformation

I would like help with R code to estimate theta for the Inverse Hyperbolic Sine Transformation.  This transformation is useful to transform skewed data that contain negative values or zeros.

There are a couple of related posts that discuss the IHS and suggest there is a maximum likelihood approach to estimating theta but I can't work out how to apply it.  These related posts are:

- [How should I transform non-negative data including zeros?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/how-should-i-transform-non-negative-data-including-zeros)
- [Inverse hyperbolic sine transformation: estimation of theta](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/inverse-hyperbolic-sine-transformation-estimation-of-theta)

Please see example code below.  I've made skewed data by using the inverse of the IHS.  Now, given the skewed data, and no prior knowledge of theta, how can I work out what theta should be? I would be most grateful for R code to undertake this analysis.

```
# Define the IHS transformation and its inverse
IHS <- function(x, theta){  # Inverse IHS transformation
  (1/theta)*asinh(theta * x)
}

Inv.IHS <- function(x, theta){  # IHS transformation
  (1/theta)*sinh(theta * x)
}

set.seed(1)
# generate some normal data
x <- rnorm(1000)
hist(x, breaks='FD')

# skew it by applying the Inverse of the IHS transformation
xt <- Inv.IHS(x, theta=2)
hist(xt, breaks='FD') # yep this is skewed.  How could we estimate theta?
```

[image: usng inverse of the IHS to skew data]

Comment: If you want to estimate it, maximum likelihood estimation, perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

After a couple more days of thinking about the problem, I have two tentative answers.

1. Select theta so that the transformed data is close to normal as measured by goodness of fit.  For example choose theta to maximize the p-value of the Shapiro-Wik test.

   ```
   set.seed(1)
   x <- rnorm(1000)
   xt <- Inv.IHS(x, theta=2)

   Shapiro.test.pvalue <- function(theta, x){ 
     x <- IHS(x, theta) 
     shapiro.test(x)$p.value 
   }

   optimise(Shapiro.test.pvalue, lower=0.001, upper=50, x=xt, maximum=TRUE)  # 2.069838
   ```
2. Maximum likelihood estimation of theta.

   Looking at the paper by [Burbidge et al.](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2288929?uid=3737536&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21103095117597) I think the likelihood function for a single variable can be expressed as follows.

   ```
   IHS.loglik <- function(theta,x){

     IHS <- function(x, theta){  # function to IHS transform
     asinh(theta * x)/theta
   }

   n <- length(x)
   xt <- IHS(x, theta)

   log.lik <- -n*log(sum((xt - mean(xt))^2))- sum(log(1+theta^2*x^2))
   return(log.lik)
   }     

   # try this on our data
   optimise(IHS.loglik, lower=0.001, upper=50, x=xt, maximum=TRUE) # 2.0407
   ```

In both cases we get close to the expected theta, which is encouraging.  But when I try the maximum likelihood approach on my real data it doesn't seem to give reasonable answers.

Comment: +1 (on both Q and A). ... "*when I try the maximum likelihood approach on my real data it doesn't seem to give reasonable answers*" - if the other approach does give reasonable answers, it might suggest a convergence problem with the maximization routine. What happens if you start it at the other estimate?

Comment: Unfortunately the shapiro version just works for small samples. It would be interesting to see an stable answer using ML.