# Back transform a number that was obtained using an inverse hyperbolic sine transformation with theta parameter

Tags: data-transformation

Suppose I have a highly skewed real-valued variable that takes on negative, zero, and positive values. One of the seemingly efficient ways to transform such a variable so that it's distribution becomes more normal-like and thus more suitable for further analyses is to use the Inverse Hyperbolic Sine (IHS) transformation (discussed in [this Stackexchange thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/how-should-i-transform-non-negative-data-including-zeros), and originally described in [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2288929)).

In its general form, IHS has a parameter $\theta$:

$f(y, \theta) = \sinh^{-1}(\theta y)/\theta = \log[\theta y + (\theta^2 y^2 + 1)^{1/2}]/\theta$

Let's assume that I've been able to estimate $\theta$ from my data and apply the transformation as specified in the above formula. As my trigonometry is extremely rusty, I'd appreciate any help with the following question: **how do I back-transform to the original scale after applying such an IHS transformation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out after some additional digging (see this [Stackexchange question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78929/how-can-i-estimate-theta-for-the-inverse-hyperbolic-sine-transformation)), the answer is very simple. If $y' = \sinh^{-1}(\theta y)/\theta$ is the transformed variable, then the reverse transformation would be as follows: $y = \sinh(\theta y')/\theta$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct - the inverse of "inverse hyperbolic sine" is indeed "hyperbolic sine". But it's probably easier to think of it flipped about -- as "the inverse of hyperbolic sine is *inverse hyperbolic sine*".